# addBetweenCondition in YII

Tags: php, sql, yii, between

SO I want to find that if value x is exits between the values of 2 columns or not, For that i have run the query in phpmyadmin :

**Normal Approch :-**

```
SELECT * FROM `traits_versions` WHERE 16 BETWEEN `trait_value_lower` and `trait_value_upper` and `style_id` = 1
```

and it is giving me fine result.But when the same approach i want to find achieve in YII that it is not running and giving the sql error :

**YII apprroch :-**

```
    $details = array();
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->addCondition('style_id='.$style_id);
        $criteria->addCondition('version='.$version);
$criteria->addBetweenCondition($style_contribution,$this->trait_value_lower,$this->trait_value_upper);
        $trait_details= $this->find($criteria);
```

When i debug the query in log than it shows in case of yii :

```
SELECT * FROM `traits_versions` `t` WHERE ((style_id=1) AND (version=1)) AND (16 BETWEEN NULL AND NULL) LIMIT 1
```

Why it is giving NULL value in query while i'm passing the name of the column in it. 
So please guide me where i'm going wrong in yii.

Comment: Did you try to echo $this->trait_value_lower to make sure the correct value is in fact there?

Comment: @jagsler yes it is correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add compare condition like below

```
$criteria->compare('trait_value_lower', 16, false, '>');
$criteria->compare('trait_value_upper',16, false, '<');
```

instead of between condition

```
$criteria->addBetweenCondition($style_contribution,$this->trait_value_lower,$this->trait_value_upper);
```

because between condition will apply on one column as per Yii doc.

```
public static addBetweenCondition(string $column, string $valueStart, string $valueEnd, string $operator='AND')
```